# Handling undefined variables from api callback

Tags: php, jquery, api

I am using PHP to make a curl call to pull data from an external api. The data type received is json.

In my jquery i have fixed variables and sometimes the callbacks from the api come back without data for these variables so in Jquery they are seen as undefined and because of this my jquery statements stops when it gets to a line where the variable is undefined.

The following error is found in the web console

> TypeError: response.endpoints[1] is undefined

There are many variables.. is there anything I can do to globally update undefined variables with "n/a" and prevent the code from stopping. Look forward to some expert advice.

sample code below

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "api5.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",

    //if received a response from the server
    success: function (response) {
            var status = response.status;
            var CVE3389 = "https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/09/10/is-beast-still-a-threat?_ga=1.235863681.1412228171.1426286790";
            var CVE0160 = "https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0160";
            var CVE0224 = "https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/04/08/ssl-labs-test-for-the-heartbleed-attack?_ga=1.235863681.1412228171.1426286790";

                if ((status == 'READY' && response.endpoints[0].statusMessage == 'Ready')) {
                // Clear DIV
                $("#ajaxResponsePending").empty();
                // Host details
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Status:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].statusMessage+ " ["+response.endpoints[0].progress+"%]<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Host:</b> " + response.host + ":" + response.port +"<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponse").append("<b>Server:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].details.serverSignature+ "<br>");
                // Vulnerabilities response endpoint 0
                $("#ajaxResponseVul").append("<b>Supports RC4:</b> " +response.endpoints[0].details.supportsRc4+ "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul").append("<b>Beast:</b> " +response.endpoints[0].details.vulnBeast+ " (CVE-2011-3389) (<a href='"+CVE3389+"' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul").append("<b>Heartbeat:</b> " +response.endpoints[0].details.heartbeat+ " (CVE-2014-0160) (<a href='"+CVE0160+"' target='_new'>more info)</a><br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul").append("<b>Heartbleed:</b> " +response.endpoints[0].details.heartbleed+ " (CVE-2014-0160) (<a href='"+CVE0160+"' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul").append("<b>OpenSSL CCS:</b> " +response.endpoints[0].details.heartbleed+ " (CVE-2014-0224) (<a href='"+CVE0224+"' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
                // Vulnerabilities response endpoint 1
                $("#ajaxResponseVul1").append("<b>Supports RC4:</b> " +response.endpoints[1].details.supportsRc4+ "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul1").append("<b>Beast:</b> " +response.endpoints[1].details.vulnBeast+ " (CVE-2011-3389) (<a href='"+CVE3389+"' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul1").append("<b>Heartbeat:</b> " +response.endpoints[1].details.heartbeat+ " (CVE-2014-0160) (<a href='"+CVE0160+"' target='_new'>more info)</a><br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul1").append("<b>Heartbleed:</b> " +response.endpoints[1].details.heartbleed+ " (CVE-2014-0160) (<a href='"+CVE0160+"' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul1").append("<b>OpenSSL CCS:</b> " +response.endpoints[1].details.heartbleed+ " (CVE-2014-0224) (<a href='"+CVE0224+"' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
                // Vulnerabilities response endpoint 2
                $("#ajaxResponseVul2").append("<b>Supports RC4:</b> " +response.endpoints[2].details.supportsRc4+ "<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul2").append("<b>Beast:</b> " +response.endpoints[2].details.vulnBeast+ " (CVE-2011-3389) (<a href='"+CVE3389+"' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul2").append("<b>Heartbeat:</b> " +response.endpoints[2].details.heartbeat+ " (CVE-2014-0160) (<a href='"+CVE0160+"' target='_new'>more info)</a><br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul2").append("<b>Heartbleed:</b> " +response.endpoints[2].details.heartbleed+ " (CVE-2014-0160) (<a href='"+CVE0160+"' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
                $("#ajaxResponseVul2").append("<b>OpenSSL CCS:</b> " +response.endpoints[2].details.heartbleed+ " (CVE-2014-0224) (<a href='"+CVE0224+"' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
```

For example, the callback will always have data for at least response.endpoints[0]... but depending on the callback there may or may not be data for response.endpoints[1].... response.endpoints[2]... etc

Let me know if you need me to clarify further..

-- UPDATE 3 --

Fixed by using one loop per the guidance from Rory.. just needed to think this through properly.. all working now using the following code:

```
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.endpoints.length; i++) {
                var endpoint1 = response.endpoints[i];
                $response0.append("<h3>Endpoint ["+i+"] <font color='green'>&#10004;</font></h3><b>Server Name:</b> " + endpoint1.serverName+ "<br>");
                $response0.append("<b>IP Address:</b> " + endpoint1.ipAddress+ "<br>");
                $response0.append("<b>Grade:</b> " + endpoint1.grade+ "<br>");
                }
```

Comment: Are you calling that `response.endpoint` item explicitly using `1`, or in a loop? Seeing the code causing the problem would really help here.

Comment: Hi Rory, i've updated my post with sample code and additional notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop to iterate through the data which was actually returned. Try this:

```
success: function (response) {
    var status = response.status;
    var CVE3389 = "https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/09/10/is-beast-still-a-threat?_ga=1.235863681.1412228171.1426286790";
    var CVE0160 = "https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0160";
    var CVE0224 = "https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/04/08/ssl-labs-test-for-the-heartbleed-attack?_ga=1.235863681.1412228171.1426286790";

    if ((status == 'READY' && response.endpoints[0].statusMessage == 'Ready')) {
        $("#ajaxResponsePending").empty();
        var $vul = $("#ajaxResponseVul");
        var $response = $("#ajaxResponse");

        // Host details
        $response.append("<b>Status:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].statusMessage + " ["+response.endpoints[0].progress+"%]<br>");
        $response.append("<b>Host:</b> " + response.host + ":" + response.port + "<br>");
        $response.append("<b>Server:</b> " + response.endpoints[0].details.serverSignature + "<br>");

        for (var i = 0; i < response.endpoints.length; i++) {
            var endpoint = response.endpoints[i];
            $vul.append("<b>Supports RC4:</b> " + endpoint.details.supportsRc4 + "<br>");
            $vul.append("<b>Beast:</b> " + endpoint.details.vulnBeast + " (CVE-2011-3389) (<a href='" + CVE3389 + "' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
            $vul.append("<b>Heartbeat:</b> " + endpoint.details.heartbeat + " (CVE-2014-0160) (<a href='" + CVE0160 + "' target='_new'>more info)</a><br>");
            $vul.append("<b>Heartbleed:</b> " + endpoint.details.heartbleed + " (CVE-2014-0160) (<a href='" + CVE0160 + "' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
            $vul.append("<b>OpenSSL CCS:</b> " + endpoint.details.heartbleed + " (CVE-2014-0224) (<a href='" + CVE0224 + "' target='_new'>more info</a>)<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: implementing this solution now.. how do we handle response.endpoints[1]...

for example the 'for statement' provided covers response.endpoints[0].supportsRc4 to endpoint.details.supportsRcs4

unsure how i would work this in for other endpoints [1], [2] and [3]

Comment: It's a loop, so will iterate over each item in the `endpoints` array. The first iteration will be over `endpoints[0]`, then `endpoints[1]` and so on. I would suggest you look in to looping in JavaScript as it's a fundamental principle in the logic.

Comment: im getting closer.. but still failing on endpoint[1] so it might be just the way i have it written.. can you take a look at my attempt (i updated my post with sample code)

Comment: The issue is because you're still attempting to explicitly retrieve array elements which don't exit, namely `endpoints[1]` and `[2]`. You need to check that they exist first, or use a loop.

Comment: right, that makes sense but i thought i did have them under the same loop you provided. should i be using a separate loop for each endpoint i.e. endpoint[1] and enpoint[2] ? sorry not sure how i would write that..

Comment: okay, i think i worked it out.. after taking your advice and reading about looping in javascript i understood what the for loop actually does.. so i dont know if this is the right thing but the errors are all gone now.. i added more for loops in and increased the i = 0 to i = 1 and i = 2  for each endpoint.. seems to work. If you can confirm this is the right way then i think we are good.

Comment: Rory, can you check my updated code in my post [UPDATE 2].. with the extra loops all the errors are gone but the output of the data is showing up tripple.. appreciate further assistance.

Comment: finally got it working with one loop using your original method.. had to remove the other instances as it was dynamically incrementing the output with one loop. I updated my post with the working code. I will flag this as resolved thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check in javascript for variable is undefined or not

for eg:

```
if(response.endpoints[1]==undefined)
{
  //your code
}

if(response.endpoints[2]==undefined)
{
  //your code
}
```

or

the other way is you can loop it

```
for(i in response.endpoints)
{
  if(i==1)
  {
    //your code with response.endpoints[i]
  }
  if(i==2)
  {
    //your code with response.endpoints[i]
  }
  if(i==3)
  {
    //your code with response.endpoints[i]
  }
}
```

the second way is dynamic but you have put conditions for each loop.

Comment: For the first option.. my condition will be way too long this way.. is it possible to set variable for undefined data? can you explain how the second option works (loop) .. if you can update my code with this i will try it